# How to stop looping an HTML5 video loop and let it play out to the end

Tags: javascript, html

I have a video that I would like to loop. After N seconds I would like it to stop looping. It should not stop immediately when the timer expires, but proceed to the end of the video and then stop.

This is my html code

```
 <video poster="images/banner-bg.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="vid/MM_Logo_Identity.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="bgvid1">
    </video>
```

script

```
document.getElementsByTagName('source').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
function myHandler(e) {
    console.log('ended');
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementsByTagName('source').play();
    }, 9000);
};
```

Comment: Try to remove the loop from your html code

Comment: ok bro got it thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `loop` attribute, like this:

```
<video poster="images/banner-bg.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted>
    <source src="vid/MM_Logo_Identity.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="bgvid1">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it may useful to you.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('source').addEventListener('ended', function() { 
   this.currentTime = 1; 
}, false);
```

Comment: Why current time? Explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As several comments mentioned, you can remove the loop attribute to get it to stop looping. You could keep it in the HTML code and then just remove it when you want to stop looping.

```
<video poster="images/banner-bg.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="vid/MM_Logo_Identity.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="bgvid1">
</video>
```

```
// after 9 seconds, stop looping the video
setTimeout(function(){
    const video = document.getElementById('bgvid');
    video.removeAttribute("loop");

    // optional: go back to the poster image when the video completes
    video.removeAttribute("autoplay"); // remove autoplay too so it doesn't start again
    video.addEventListener('ended', function() { video.load(); });
}, 9000);
```